# how to deny access to all pages and allow only for certain on wiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I'm using mediawiki 1.13.3 running on freebsd 7.4
I've got confused with the following task:
how to deny access to All pages for certain users (who has account in my wiki) or for group of these users but allow ReadOnly access for certain pages on wiki. 
The goal to achieve is to have no access to pages on wiki except allowed few for some users.

I've tried some extensions but can't find a solution for ~20000 pages and few hundreds of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [*Manual:Preventing access* on mediawiki.org, section "Restrict viewing of all pages"](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aPreventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_all_pages).

Specifically, to allow everyone to read (but not edit) the *Main Page* and a page named *Public stuff*, and to allow only sysops to read and edit all pages, you'd add the following lines to your LocalSettings.php:

```php
# prevent editing and reading by anons (except for exception listed below):
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;

# same for normal registered users:
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['read'] = false;

# allow everyone read access to these pages:
$wgWhitelistRead = array( "Main Page", "Public stuff" );

# allow sysops to read and edit normally:
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['edit'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['read'] = true;
```

Of course, you can replace `sysop` above with your own [custom user group](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgGroupPermissions#Custom_user_groups); I just used it in the example because it exists in a stock MediaWiki install.

(Some older example code suggests also including `"Special:UserLogin"` and possibly `"Special:ChangePassword"` and `"Special:PasswordReset"` in [`$wgWhitelistRead`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgWhitelistRead).  In modern MediaWiki versions this should be unnecessary, although still harmless.)

Comment: Thank, but I've read about $wgGroupPermissions and found this is not what I need. Even more, mixing group permissions and simplesecurity extention I can achieve the goal, but.. than I've found we are using  "Labeled Section Transclusion" extension and simple tags like {{#lst:Namespace:PageName}} will neutralize all security.

Comment: You might want to try setting [`$wgNonincludableNamespaces`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNonincludableNamespaces), although I'm not sure if [LST](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Labeled_Section_Transclusion) respects it or not. If not, that's arguably a bug in the extension.

Answer (score 0):

A quite close solution I've found is using simple security extension:
So I'm creating a user group with no access:

`$wgGroupPermissions['user']['read'] = false;`

add this group to *$wgRestrictionLevels = array();*

and then restricting read access for some pages to this group.

Fairly enough but not exactly the solution I want to achieve.